# How to save card details using Braintree?

Tags: react-native, braintree, credit-card

Currently, I'm using the following third-party libraries to integrate with Braintree:

- https://github.com/ferndopolis/react-native-braintree-card
- https://github.com/kraffslol/react-native-braintree-xplat

But I'm not able to find any method to save card details. Is there a rest API call available to save card details?

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

Both of the third-party libraries you linked to are wrappers for our client SDKS and have documentation that show that you will need to return the resulting [payment method nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-method-nonces) to your server-side to use. A payment method nonce is a secure, one-time-use reference to payment information. It's the key element that allows your server to communicate sensitive payment information to Braintree without ever touching the raw data.

Braintree does not have a REST API at this moment, however you can use [one of our server SDKS](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/) to run a [Customer Create API Call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/ruby), which will save that customer's payment information into the Braintree Vault. Additionally, you could run a [Payment Method Create API Call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/) as well to save the card details.

Comment: How do you use a saved payment method?